# Split CardViews as in Google Material Design Example

Tags: android

I want to enter another `Activity` and the `CardView` that holds the login/pass fields split into 3 and each one becomes a round `CardView`.

For now i tried doing a shared element transition. the problem is, i have to set 3 pairs of shared transitions so when it begins, spawns 2 more `CardView`s and then they become the `Button`s. This is the example from google: [Video](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0B0NGgBg38lWWbE1WWExWSURmTDg/whatismaterial-materialprop-transformingmaterial-020202_PaperHeal_xhdpi_003.webm)

This is whats happening: [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYipE.png)

I have no idea how to implement this, help? 
Thanks in advance